# What's the order of scoring when completing a city with a Princess?

Tags: carcassonne

Yesterday, I played with *The Dragon, the Fairy and the Princess* for the first time. We came upon a situation that wasn't completely clear in the rules.

What if there's an almost completed city, with one of Alice's followers in it, and Bob completes that city on his turn, with a Princess tile (which removes a knight from the city the tile is added to)?

Is Alice's knight removed, after which the city's score goes to nobody, or does Alice get the points, after which the Princess has no knight left to remove?

I found an answer which I'll add below, but I'd like to hear your input as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer I found on [BoardGameGeek.com](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/326644/princess-closing-a-city-and-removing-a-knight) divides the turn into three phases:

1. Draw and place tile.
2. Place and move meeple (place or remove follower, move dragon and so on).
3. Score points.

So that would mean that Alice doesn't get any points, because her knight is removed before she can get any points, and this city's points are lost.

Comment: Yes, scoring always happens last.

Comment: Step 2 [doesn't take place](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/13807/1050) if the Princess removes a follower.

Comment: @Aldaron Actually, I meant the Princess removing a folllower as one possible action in phase 2.

Comment: @SQB: Now you've changed the step numbers to something I think no one will recognize. In your new system, "step 4" does not occur and the Princess may remove a follower in "step 3". Note also that your "step 1" is not part of the turn technically (in the context of turns that the builder's power repeats).

Comment: @Aldaron I agree, rolled back.

Answer (score 2):

[If](http://www.sciencegames.com/carcassonne/) a tile with a Princess symbol, is added to a city in which there are already followers, then the placing player *may* (the "BigBox" rules still say "must"): select one follower (of any player) to remove from that city and return to its owner and *skip the deployment stage*, after which scoring occurs.

So a follower removed by the Princess will be absent when scoring takes place. But note also that

- points may still be scored for the city if there are other followers in it,
- removing a follower is optional, and
- no figure can be played (and the Dragon will not move, etc.) if the player chooses to use the Princess to remove a follower.

Comment: The Dragon will not move? There's no piece with both a Princess and a Dragon symbol on it, but if there were, _surely_ the Dragon would start moving, wouldn't he?

Comment: @SQB: No. Dragon movement occurs in step 2 (step 4 in your numbering system), which is skipped if the Princess's figure-removal power is used.

Comment: I can't find that anywhere in [the rules](http://riograndegames.com/getFile.php?id=684). What it _does_ say, is that the dragon moves after followers have been placed. Since follower placement is replaced by knight removal, I'd say dragon movement comes after knight removal. But that's all academical, since I don't think there's a way to be faced with both knight removal and dragon movement.

Comment: @SQB: Follower placement isn't "replaced" by knight removal: all of step 2 in skipped. Whether step 2 includes Dragon movement is up to you. HiG rulings imply that it happens (if it could happen) in step 2; RGG's Big Box rules have (or at least had) it happening *after* scoring!